# How to force BITS to download WSUS updates in foreground in Win Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, bits

As you know, WSUS use BITS for downloading its updates. Unfortunately BITS downloads these updates in background and use remained bandwidth of server. This is not desirable in my situation that want to get all update rapidly. I want to force BITS to download WSUS updates in foreground (instead of background). Is there any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change this settings using windows gui. Open a Powershell and run following commands:

```
$conf=(get-wsusserver).GetConfiguration()
$conf.BitsDownloadPriorityForeground=$true
$conf.save()
```

Comment: Thisa worked for me, I have been trying to download 6 patches totaling 2.5g for 10 days. Never got past 100mb.
I ran the 3 lines above and boom I am at 1gb in less than 2min. I tried every other fix I could find. This IS the fix.